# Run SQL Script programatically

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql script like this:

```
select id,
       name,
       address,
       age,
       sex
from table1
left join table2 <condition>
left join table3 <condition>
where name = 'Harry Potter';
```

Is there a way that I call and run this script but change the name of interest without editing the original script?
For instance,
I want to run this line instead.

```
where name = 'Lebron James'
```

I am using PostgreSQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your query in a function while replacing the `name` string by an input parameter `input_name` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (input_name text)
RETURNS table (id int, name text, address text, age int, sex text) 
LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
select id,
       name,
       address,
       age,
       sex
from table1
left join table2 <condition>
left join table3 <condition>
where name = input_name  ;
$$
```

Then `SELECT * FROM test('Lebron James')` should return the right query result.

Comment: I got id,name,address,age and sex squeezed into one column named test. How do I get the result with separate columns instead?

Comment: @AlexWong: the example should use `returns table` instead, and then you should use `select * from test(...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the update. however, it seems not to work for me to expand the columns, they are still squeezed into a single column with a bracket. e.g the outcome is like (1, Harry Potter, Manhattan, 15, M)

Comment: @AlexWong: you probably used `select test(...)` and not `select * from test(...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, thanks a lot!!